# Default namespace when created xml document

Tags: c#, xml

Is it possible to create children using XmlDocument.CreateElement() and XmlNode.AppendChild() without specifying the namespace and have it use a "default" namespace?

Currently, if I create a root node with a namespace and don't specify the namespace on the every childnode, the output xml will define a blank namespace.

Below is what is generated if I don't specify the namespace for every element I create.  Is there a shortcut where I don't have to specify the namespace every time?

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
  <child1 xmlns="">
    <child2 />
  </child1>
</root>
```

Code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var rootNode = doc.CreateElement("root", "http://example.com");
doc.AppendChild(rootNode);
var child1Node = doc.CreateElement("child1");
rootNode.AppendChild(child1Node);
var child2Node = doc.CreateElement("child2");
child1Node.AppendChild(child2Node);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have create your XML document, and you specify the same namespace for each element in the hierarchy - something like this:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        const string xmlNS = "http://www.example.com";

        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("root", xmlNS);
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        XmlElement child1 = doc.CreateElement("child1", xmlNS);
        root.AppendChild(child1);

        child1.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("child2", xmlNS));

        doc.Save(@"D:\test.xml");
```

then you'll get this output file:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.example.com">
  <child1>
    <child2 />
  </child1>
</root>
```

The namespace on the `<root>` node is inherited down the hierarchy, unless the child elements define something else explicitly.

If you create a new XmlElement using `doc.CreateElement` and you don't specify a XML namespace, then of course, that new element, will have a blank namespace and thus this will be serialized into that XML document you had.

I am not aware of any way to specify a default namespace to use whenever you're creating a new element - if you specify one, the element will use that namespace - if you don't specify one, it's the blank namespace.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 3.5, I suggest using LINQ to XML, (System.Xml.Linq). Use the XDocument, XElement, and XAttribute classes.

But marc_s's answer is correct, the namespace is inherited.

Comment: Erm, marc_s's answer doesn't say the namespace is inherited.  It says you have to manually specify it for every XML element you create.